# ¿Cómo añadir elemento al final de la lista cuando tengo dos querys?

Tags: java, sql

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT sum(cast(r.importe as float)),r.entidad,r.referencia,r.moneda_id "
                    + "from envio_remesa er "
                    + "inner join Remesa r "
                    + "on er.id = r.envio_remesa_id "
                    + "where r.envio_remesa_id = 3 and r.tipo_doc='101' "
                    + "GROUP BY entidad,referencia,r.moneda_id ORDER BY entidad ASC");
            
            ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery("select sum(cast(montante as float)),entidad,referencia "
                    + "from documento d "
                    + "inner join remesa r "
                    + "on d.remesa_id = r.id "
                    + "inner join envio_remesa er "
                    + "on r.envio_remesa_id = er.id "
                    + "where er.id = 3 and r.tipo_doc='101' group by entidad,referencia");
            
            while(rs.next()) {
                List<Object> ls = new ArrayList<>();
                Float sumaImporte = rs.getFloat(1);
                Integer entidad = rs.getInt(2);
                Integer referencia = rs.getInt(3);
                ls.add(sumaImporte);
                ls.add(entidad);
                ls.add(referencia);
                System.out.println(ls);
                
            }
            
            while(rs2.next()) {
                Integer referenciaQuery2 = rs2.getInt(2);
                System.out.println("Suma---> "+rs2.getFloat(1));
            }
```

Tengo estas dos queries **rs** y **rs2**, de la primera obtengo listas con 3 campos(sumaImporte,entidad y referencia) , seguidamente quiero de la segunda query llamada rs2, añadir el rs2.getFloat(1) al final de la lista ls. He intentado varias cosas pero no lo he conseguido. Alguien se le ocurre alguna manera?

Osea el resultado de abajo donde pone "Suma--> xxx", es lo que quiero añadir al final de la lista
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EJEMPLO:

```
[[15500.0, 18, 134,75.69(valor que quiero añadir)], [66600.0, 18, 135,25.23(valor que quiero añadir)], [16900.0, 18, 136,0(si no coincide referenciaQuery2 con rs.getInt(3) se añade un 0)]
```

Tablas:
**Remesa**:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Documento**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Envio_Remesa**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1 envio de remesa puede tener n remesas.
1 remesa puede tener n documentos.

Comment: Declara ```List<Object> ls = new ArrayList<>();```, antes del primer while, asi podríás agregar los demas datos en el segundo while

Comment: Así se concatenan todos, y no es lo que busco

Comment: Agrega un ejemplo del resultado esperado.

Comment: @Sal ya he editado

Comment: Lo correcto seria utilizar un solo query.

Comment: @Alvarez Lo sé pero no me sale con una query. ¿Alguna idea de como mejorarlo?

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos las tablas envio_remesa, Remesa, documento. Veo que el where va filtrado por los mismos campos. Asumiria que solo necesitas otro join para documento vs remesa.

Comment: @Alvarez Acabo de adjuntar las tablas y la relación que hay entre ellas

Comment: Puedes indicar los 4 campos que requieres.

Comment: referencia,entidad, la suma del montante de los documentos que pertenecen a una remesa de un envío en concreto, la suma de importe que es la el importe donde n remesas pertenecen a un envío @Alvarez

Comment: Pon la segunda consulta en el `FROM` de la primera y haz `LEFT JOIN` con `entidad` y `referencia`.

Comment: @Sal Pon el código como respuesta y si funciona te marco como correcta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo fácil es convertir la segunda consulta en una vista en la primera:

```
SELECT sum(cast(r.importe as float))
     , r.entidad
     , r.referencia
     , r.moneda_id
     , t.suma
  FROM envio_remesa er
    INNER JOIN Remesa r
      ON er.id = r.envio_remesa_id
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT sum(cast(montante as float)) suma
                     , entidad
                     , referencia
                  FROM documento d
                    INNER JOIN remesa r
                      ON d.remesa_id = r.id
                    INNER JOIN envio_remesa er
                      ON r.envio_remesa_id = er.id
                  WHERE er.id = 3 
                    AND r.tipo_doc='101' 
                  GROUP BY entidad, referencia
              ) t
      ON    t.entidad = r.entidad
        AND t.referencia = r.referencia
  WHERE r.envio_remesa_id = 3 
    AND r.tipo_doc='101'
  GROUP BY r.entidad, r.referencia, r.moneda_id 
  ORDER BY r.entidad ASC
```

Con la reserva de conocer la dependencia entre `r.id` y `r.referencia` se podría reducir a:

```
SELECT sum(cast(r.importe as float))
     , r.entidad
     , r.referencia
     , r.moneda_id
     , sum(cast(d.montante as float)) suma2
  FROM envio_remesa er
    INNER JOIN Remesa r
      ON er.id = r.envio_remesa_id
    LEFT JOIN documento d
      ON d.remesa_id = r.id
  WHERE r.envio_remesa_id = 3 
    AND r.tipo_doc='101'
  GROUP BY entidad, referencia, r.moneda_id 
  ORDER BY entidad ASC
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciona perfectamente, pero.. Me gustaría saber el por qué usar LEFT JOIN en esta consulta? Gracias de ante mano

Comment: Para mantener el pivote actual y no filtrar las remesas que no tengan documento; es lo que te permite ver sumas cero.